# Arithmetic overflow error converting datetime's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which stores date information in nvarchar in the format of (dd/mm/yyyy),When I convert this column to datetime using Convert(nvarchar(100), dt, 101)  it doesn’t have any issue ,However when I want to select top x rows from it like ,I got the following error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2,Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

The following is the sample of my code:

```
declare @d as nvarchar(100);
SET @d='20/11/2012'

SELECT
    top  1  @d,
    (select date_diff = DATEDIFF(
        day, 
        CAST(Convert(nvarchar(100), @d, 101) as DateTime),
        '2014-10-01 00:00:00')) d
```

Comment: "I get anerror" is not a problem description (in fact, "anerror" is not even a word). What **specific error** do you get? Questions should be specific, and you have the error information right in front of you - why did you not include it in your question so we'd have it too? (Remember that for future questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just SQL interpreting the first date time as  the 11th day of the 20th Month in the year 2012.

Try in one of SQL's [preferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) date formats.

My preferred format is the `dd-MMM-yyyy` because it is never ambiguous:

```
declare @d as nvarchar(100);
SET @d='20-Nov-2012'


SELECT
    top  1  @d,
    (select date_diff = DATEDIFF(
        day, 
        CAST(Convert(nvarchar(100), @d, 101) as DateTime),
        '01-OCt-2014 00:00:00')) d
```

SQL picks the [date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) based on the language.

You can also be explicit and tell it to use `dmy` format in your query like so:

```
SET DATEFORMAT 'dmy'
```

Based on the comments below I am inferring this sort of query:

```
--Pretending to be some table in the database with varchar dates :(
create table #test (dt varchar(100))
insert #test values ('20/11/2012')


SET DATEFORMAT 'dmy'    --Works
--SET DATEFORMAT 'mdy'  --Doesn't Work

SELECT
    top  1  dt,
    (select date_diff = DATEDIFF(
        day, 
        CAST(Convert(nvarchar(100), dt, 101) as DateTime),
        '2014-10-01 00:00:00')) d
from #test

drop table #test
```

But in this case where we are selecting a varchar date from a table, that setting the date format correct's the issue. Try testing with the differing `dateformat`s.

Comment: My issue is the data store in the database in this format  '20/11/2012' .

Comment: So `@d` is a value selected from another query / table? P.S. This is why you should never store dates as varchar's ;)

Comment: I found the solution ,I should you  Convert(nvarchar(100), dt, 103)

Comment: +1 for converting a horrible question into a nice and useful one.